# NIO load file in an unit test from src/test/resources

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, nio

**The Problem**

I'd like to write a data import in java with java7s NIO. The user enters the path of a file as a String and the programm try to open it by using Paths. When it want to read its DosFileAttributes an java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file.txt occures.

**What i've found**

The only answers i've found till yet is to use an resource Stream - but this seams not practicable, because the file to be loaded is provided by the user and should not be part of the jar. Or did i missunderstood it? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29

**What i've got**

The Setup:

- Maven 3
- Java7
- TestNG
- Spring

Project Structure:

- src/main/java - the classes
- src/test/java - the testcases
- src/test/resources - perhaps file.txt ? actual it is there

The source that loads the file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.DosFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component( "fileLoader" )
public class BufferdFileLoader
        implements FileLoader {

    @Override
    public List<String> loadFile( String path )
            throws IOException {

        if ( path == null || path.length() == 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "path should not be null" );
        }

        Path file = Paths.get( path );

        // here the Exception is thrown
        DosFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes( file, DosFileAttributes.class );

        if ( !attrs.isRegularFile() ) {
            throw new IOException( "could not read file, invalid path" );
        }

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader( file, Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) )) {
            String line = null;
            while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
                result.add( line );
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And the Test case is as simple:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * Class under test {@link BufferdFileLoader}
 * 
 */
@ContextConfiguration
public class BufferdFileLoaderTest
        extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    /**
     * Class under test
     */
    @Inject
    @Setter
    private BufferdFileLoader bufferdFileLoader;


    /**
     * Method under test {@link BufferdFileLoader#loadFile(String)}
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Test( groups = { "integration" }, enabled = true )
    public void testImportFeedsFromXMLFileWitEmptyXml()
            throws IOException {

        String filename = "empty-example-takeout.xml";

        List<String> list = this.bufferdFileLoader.loadFile( filename );

        Assert.assertEquals( list.size(), 0 );

    }

}
```

**So my question is**

How to load a file using NIO so it is testable with maven and also works in production environment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it's a matter of obtaining the correct `Path` for you test resource in the classpath in your test.

**EDIT:** this is more concise:

```
Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/"+filename).toURI()).toString()
```

Comment: i get your point there, test is working fine now. but i want it to run in the jar too. java -jar app f:\myfile.txt won't run with the .getResource as mentioned above

Comment: @Thomas : the snippet in my answer is supposed to replace the relevant code in **your test method**. You **shouldn't** apply that change your to `loadFile` method - it should remain as-is. The snippet simply provides the string that corresponds to the path classifier of your test file, so that it it can be converted back into a `Path` in `loadFile` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a folder named `testing` you can use the following:

```
Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/testing").toURI()).resolve(filename)
```

The other method will throw a null pointer exception if the file does not exists